# SBT `CrossProject` build broken with custom compile target

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

Getting "Overlapping output directories" sbt error with custom compile target (ramdisk on `/tmp/sbt/`) defined for a Scala.js `CrossProject` based build.

FWIW, have used above compile target seamlessly in SBT projects for 3 years running. The error does *not* occur when using sbt default compile target (i.e. build project root). Kind of a show stopper since my tooling is geared around ramdisk setup.

Here's the actual error:

```
Overlapping output directories:/tmp/sbt/foo:
[error]     ProjectRef(file:/home/me/path/to/project/,fooJS)
[error]     ProjectRef(file:/home/me/path/to/project/,fooJVM)
```

Have tried subclassing [`CrossType`](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/sbtplugin/cross/CrossType.scala) as suggested [in the docs](http://www.scala-js.org/api/sbt-scalajs/0.6.5/#org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject), overriding `projectDir` and `sharedSrcDir` to no avail, same error. Here's [SBT source location](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/sxr/sbt/Project.scala.html#sbt.Project.checkTargets) where overlapping targets are checked.

I'm wondering why this occurs with a custom compile target, but not the default target? More importantly, how can I get a custom compile target working with Scala.js' `crossProject`?

Comment: What is the sbt config you use to define your custom compile target?

Comment: @sjrd I forked your scalajs-cross-compile github project. Here's a gist of build: https://gist.github.com/godenji/a161be68fabc988fb5fa

Comment: Tried various things like changing from `file(".")` to `file("module")`, and breaking `projectDir` and `sharedSrcDir` into separate directories, same error regardless.

Comment: @sjrd oh, compile target is defined globally in my `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`, which consists of: `target <<= (name) {(name) => file("/tmp/sbt/") / name }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you're customizing the target directory like this:

```
target <<= (name) { (name) => file("/tmp/sbt") / name }
```

which, in 0.13 notation, means this:

```
target := file("/tmp/sbt") / name.value
```

This will cause problems with cross-projects because both the JVM and JS variants of a `crossProject` have the same `name` by default, and hence both projects will indeed end up with the same target directory, which causes your conflict.

You have two possibilities to fix this. Either you change the `name` settings so that they are not the same (but then you need to re-customize the `normalizedName`s so that they're the same again), or you change the way you compute the `target` so that it will be different.

First solution:

```
lazy val foo = crossProject.in(...).
  jvmSettings(name := name.value + "-jvm").
  jsSettings(name := name.value + "-js").
  settings(
    normalizedName := normalizedName.value.stripSuffix("-jvm").stripSuffix("-js")
  ).
  // other settings
```

That's not very elegant. I suggest the other approach, for example:

```
target := {
  /* Hacky way to detect whether this is a Scala.js project
   * without pulling the Scala.js sbt plugin on the classpath.
   */
  val isScalaJS = libraryDependencies.value.exists { dep =>
    dep.name.startsWith("scalajs-library") // not tested
  }
  file("/tmp/sbt") / (name.value + (if (isScalaJS) "-js" else ""))
}
```

Not very elegant either because of the hack, but at least you only need it once in your global config.

Comment: Hack is more than welcome -- not being able to share code between jvm and js projects was stopping me from going all-in on Scala.js (i.e. completely dropping existing untyped Coffeescript code base). Problem solved, thanks!!